# How to force YouTube to generate subtitles or caption automatically?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I am having a hard time with my studying. I have to take many courses in Korean but I don't know any Korean. I tried to record the video lecture and then upload it on YouTube automatically to have subtitles or captions but it doesn't work at all.

Does anyone know how to force YouTube to generate captions or subtitles automatically?

Answer (score -1):

Add yt:cc=on as a tag. Hope it helps :)